# sqlplus hangs with BEGIN END

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Consider the following sqlplus script:

```
select * from dual;

select * from dual;

declare
   foo number(10);
begin
   select 'abc' from dual;

end;
```

Now if I run it:

```
sqlplus user/password@DB @myscript.sql
```

I get this output:

```
D
-
X


D
-
X

  7
```

and sqlplus hangs... waiting for user input for some strange reason. If I press enter it prints 8 ... 9 ... 10 etc.

It seems like a script containing simple sql is fine, but if I put in a declare .. begin .. end sequence it isn't happy..

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PL/SQL block requires an ending slash `/` character which tells SQL*Plus that it should now run that piece of code.

```
SQL> select * From dual;

D
-
X

SQL> declare
  2    foo number(10);
  3  begin
  4    select 1 into foo from dual;
  5  end;
  6
  7
  8  /                --> this

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks. It boggles my mind that mid way executing a script from a file it decides to seek input from the console, but so be it I guess. I'm also curious why sqlplus can't see the block has ended and execute it. That's the way most shells work, when the current construct is complete it is executed.

Comment: I was also not aware that I can't just do a select in a block and have it come out on the console. Strange, but so be it.

Comment: You're welcome. That's the way it works in Oracle. I don't know why PL/SQL requires an ending slash **in certain tools** (such as SQL*Plus). GUI tools don't require it, but there you run the script by e.g. pressing a "Run" button. Though, note that if you run everything (multiple PL/SQL blocks, CREATE TYPEs and similar) you have in the Worksheet window, Oracle might raise an error if you DON'T terminate them with a slash. Larry Ellison probably knows why Oracle does it that way (if he still remembers what he did back in the late 1970's).

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, either `;` (after the statement) or `/` (on a newline) is used to terminate a statement.

In PL/SQL, `;` (after the statement) is used to terminate statements and `/` (on a newline) is used to terminate the PL/SQL block. You are missing the block terminator; which means that the database does not know that the code is finished and ready to be executed, which is why it is hanging because it's waiting for you to tell it that the code block is complete.

Once you enter `/` on a newline then the PL/SQL block will be executed. At that point, you will get an exception because you are using `SELECT ... FROM ...` and that is missing an `INTO` clause, which is required in PL/SQL.

It should be:

```sql
select * from dual;

select * from dual;

declare
   foo VARCHAR2(10);                 -- Wrong data type
begin
   select 'abc' INTO foo from dual;  -- Missing INTO clause
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(foo);        -- Optionally, do something with the variable.
end;
/
```